# Splitting Data by Columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is 640 rows by 50,002 columns. I need to split the data columns 2:50001 into 5 equal groups. I have tried the split and sample commands but it gave an error.

Comment: We can try `split.default(df1[-1], rep(1:4, each = 12500))`

Comment: One question my dimension ended up being 639 rows instead of 640 rows, would taking out the [-1] make the data go back to the orginal 640 rows

Comment: Please check if you data is data.frame.  If that is the case, it should work fine

Comment: @李哲源 yes that is correct column 1 and 50,002 are unused so not needed. so df1[,2:50002] gave me the data i needed